# Kotlin : Type mismatch when class implement Serializable

Tags: kotlin, type-mismatch

I have a project that was written in both Java & Kotlin (forgive my very newbie kotlin understanding)

The class I would like to serialize has implemented the `Serializable` interface.

Error Message:

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is EntityRelationship but Serializable! was expected
```

```
public class EntityRelationship implements Serializable {
    @NonNull
    private Relationship relationship;
    @Builder.Default
    private List<Relationship> childRelationship = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

When I tried to serialize it

```
val entityRelationship: EntityRelationship = relationshipList.get(0)

val serializedResponse = SerializationUtils.serialize(entityRelationship) //<--Trouble in this line
```

I do not understand why type mismatch happen here, because entityRelationship already implement serializable interface.  Even if I enforce

```
val entityRelationship: Serializable = relationshipList.get(0)
```

p.s: relationshipList is a List

I still get the same error. My zero understanding regards to kotlin forbid me to ping the issue. Any pointer is appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the definition of `relationshipList` and also is `SerializationUtils` from springframework ?

Comment: `EntityRelationship implements Serializable`, but does `RelationshipClass` (shown in the error message?)

Comment: sorry, @ Alexey Romanov, I made an mistake, the RelationshipClass is actually EntityRelationship. (due to confidential reason, I renamed the class), also the Relationship class also implement Serializable.

Comment: @aldrin relationshipList is List<EntityRelationship>, and SerializationUtils is from org.apache.commons.lang public class SerializationUtils

Comment: @user2386301 the code you listed looks good to me, I don't see any problems with it and I checked in an IDE too. Unless I'm missing something...

Comment: What I do is that I specifically cast the type val serializedResponse = SerializationUtils.serialize(entityRelationship as Serializable) to get rid of the error, and I know of a fact that with or without casting, I can serialize and deserialize properly. It just that the compiler kept fail at type mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

First of all "Relationship" class should be implemented Serializable as well. And you may need to make your serialize function generic and cast your class in SerializationUtils.

Comment: yes, so all the Relationship class implemented Serializable.  Can you specify how do I make my function generic and cast class ?